# English translation of Paul Dedecker 1964 on non abelian $\mathrm{Hom}$

Tags: translation, paper-request

Does there exist an English translation of P. Dedecker. Le foncteur $\mathrm{Hom}$ non abélien. Applications de la notion de poulpe, C. R. Acad.
Sci. Paris?

[image]

Thanks in advance.